# I bought Minecraft PE on kindle and want to play on ipad?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I bought Minecraft PE on kindle and want to play on ipad? Can this be done or do i have to re-buy?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to re-buy it if you want to obtain it legitimately. Same with buying an app on Android then wanting the same app on an iDevice

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't share or transfer an app purchase from your Kindle or other Android device to your iPad, or vice versa.  There are some exceptions for in-app purchases (like comic book apps), but generally, purchases from one marketplace will not transfer to a device on another marketplace.  This is the case for MCPE.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you bought the game from Amazon Appstore, but they do not develop and publish the iOS version, since this is against Apple's policy/EULA. So if you want your Minecraft PE Version on your iPad, you need to rebuy it from Apple's official App Store.